# Why was I awarded an Excavator badge today when I didn't earn it?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, edit-badges

I was recently [awarded an excavator badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/102/excavator?userid=8737) for something that I did not do. Is this a bug of some sort?

The question that I supposedly excavated was last edited several months ago, and I have not edited any questions recently either. My recent activity was limited to a few upvotes and comments. (I did edit the comments).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't understand why you say that you don't deserve this badge.

You *[definitely](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/3973/2)* edited that question, on May 19, 2011. The last activity on that question was back in October 13, 2010 when systempuntoout originally posted it and RegDwight [answered it](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3973/retrieves-and-let-you-print-or-retrieves-and-lets-you-print/3975#3975).

The reason you only earned it today is because the badge is *brand new*, and just got awarded for the first time today.

Comment: Thanks, how quickly I forget what happened months ago...

Comment: Oh, so *that's* why I suddenly got it on three separate SE sites in one day!

Answer (score 15):

This badge is new; it was just introduced today. That's why it came with a delay of 3 months – technically, you earned it back then. It just didn't exist yet.

Answer (score 6):

The badge has been introduced only today, and it's awarded retroactively.